# How do I delete my initial commits in git?

Tags: git

When making my first git project, for my first two commits I ended up adding way too many files.

I figured that I could delete them completely, but when I ran git **git rebase -i HEAD~10** and then put a d before the first two commits, I got this message: **error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:** ... (A bunch of files)... **Please move or remove them before you can switch branches. Aborting could not detach HEAD**

Is there a way to just remove the initial and second commit completely? If not, is there an easy way to get rid of ~40 files in the first 2 commits without manually going to the commits and taking them out?

Comment: It would be a difficult procedure. Can you start a new repository and redo your handful of commits?

Comment: Not sure if you've made more commits since the first two, but if you want to just start over, you can erase the .git directory, and then freshly add all the files again -- excluding those you don't want.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity,I already made a handful of commits after the first two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a command like this to delete files from commits:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <file>' FIRST_COMMIT..LAST_COMMIT
```

[See git-filter-branch - Rewrite branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)

Comment: When I have time ill try this command :). Just to be clear, will this delete the actual files, or will it just stop tracking them in my repo?

Comment: Delete locally, stop tracking, delete file from all commits you point to and rewrite commits history and SHA